# How can I take a screenshot of a specific portion of my screen?

Tags: screenshots, 3.1-honeycomb, samsung-galaxy-tab-8.9

There is no screenshot by area on my Galaxy Tab 8.9, running Android 3.1.

Is there any software that adds the ability to take a screenshot of only a portion of my screen rather than the whole area?

Comment: Since when does Super User develop the Android operating system or Samsung tablets?

Comment: What do you mean by "screenshot by area"? Like taking a screenshot of a specific portion of the screen rather than the entire screen?

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, I want to take a specific portion of  the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no tool with this feature. But it is possible to crop the picture in the gallery.